# Remove References section in Beamer document using bibtex/natbib

Tags: beamer, bibtex, natbib, section-titles

I have a beamer document and am using the `natbib` package with `apalike` style. Now this automatically creates a section for the references, which appears in the header of all slides as "References". How can I remove this section, i.e. not make it show up in the header anymore?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\citep{amos}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliography{my_bibtex}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

my_bibtex:

```
@misc{amos,
doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.2206.05262},
url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.05262},
author = {Amos, Brandon and Cohen, Samuel and Luise, Giulia and Redko, Ievgen},
keywords = {Machine Learning (cs.LG), Artificial Intelligence (cs.AI), Machine Learning (stat.ML), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
title = {Meta Optimal Transport},
publisher = {arXiv},
year = {2022},
copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `\bibsection` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{amos,
doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.2206.05262},
url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.05262},
author = {Amos, Brandon and Cohen, Samuel and Luise, Giulia and Redko, Ievgen},
keywords = {Machine Learning (cs.LG), Artificial Intelligence (cs.AI), Machine Learning (stat.ML), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
title = {Meta Optimal Transport},
publisher = {arXiv},
year = {2022},
copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\citep{amos}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thank you!

Comment: @joinijo You're welcome!